# The relation surface charge density $σ$ to curvature $1/R$ and compare it to capacitors

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, capacitance

the relation σ to 1/R , in which σ is the surface charge density and R is the radius of curvature, suggests that the charge placed on an isolated conductor concentrates on points and avoids flat surfaces. How do we reconcile this with c= epsilon x A / d , in which the charge is definitely on the flat surface of either plate?

Answer (score 1):

You approximate by saying that a linear dimension of a plate is much larger than the separation of the plates. This approximation makes the effect of the ends/edges of the capacitor less significant. The equal you quote for the capacitance is an approximation.